# TeamFoundation 11 Client Libraries in Nuget?

Tags: tfs, nuget

I have inherited a code base that has .dll's in the source code repository.

:::::::Gasssssssssssssssssspppppppp::::::::::

```
\ThirdPartyReferences\FromProgramFiles.11.0\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.dll"      "11.0.60315.1 built by: Q11REL"
\ThirdPartyReferences\FromProgramFiles.11.0\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.dll"      "11.0.60315.1"
\ThirdPartyReferences\FromProgramFiles.11.0\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.dll"      "11.0.50727.1"
\ThirdPartyReferences\FromProgramFiles.11.0\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.dll"      "11.0.61030.0"

\ThirdPartyReferences\FromProgramFiles.11.0\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.dll"      "11.0.60315.1"

\ThirdPartyReferences\FromProgramFiles.11.0\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Common.dll"      "11.0.61219.0 built by: Q11REL"

\ThirdPartyReferences\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.dll"      "11.0.61030.0"
\ThirdPartyReferences\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client.dll"      "11.0.61030.0"   
\ThirdPartyReferences\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestImpact.BuildIntegration.dll"      "11.0.61030.0" 

\ThirdPartyReferences\FromGAC\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestImpact.Client.dll"      "11.0.61219.0"
```

I cannot find a Nuget package that houses these.

This package

```
<package id="Microsoft.TeamFoundation.11" version="11.0.50727.1" targetFramework="net45" />
```

has these files

```
\packages\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.11.11.0.50727.1\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.11.0.0.0\lib\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.dll"      "11.0.50727.1 built by: RTMREL"
\packages\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.11.11.0.50727.1\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.11.0.0.0\lib\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.dll"      "11.0.50727.1"
\packages\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.11.11.0.50727.1\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.11.0.0.0\lib\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.dll"      "11.0.50727.1"
\packages\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.11.11.0.50727.1\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.11.0.0.0\lib\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.dll"      "11.0.50727.1"
```

Any idea where to find the others?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the package at nuget.org.

TeamFoundation.11 is located [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/TeamFoundation.11/)

Comment: I appreciate the effort.  I mentioned that one in my original post.  "<package id="Microsoft.TeamFoundation.11" version="11.0.50727.1" targetFramework="net45" />"

Comment: @granadaCoder, have you searched your VS installation folder?

Comment: I have the dll's.  That's not the issue.  In the "new world", you try to get all binaries from a binary-repository...and not store them in source-control.